# How to solve JS errror in third party package - react-force-graph

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, npm

I would like to use [react-force-graph](https://github.com/vasturiano/react-force-graph) in my app, but I am getting an error **Uncaught TypeError: selection.interrupt is not a function**. The error comes from zoom.js which is dependency of react-forrce-graph package.

I found that the problem could be solved by downgrading the d3-selection package from version 1.3.2 to version 1.3.0. How to do it? I am able to co id by changing version dependency in package.json in react-force-graph package, bud after updating packages the change will be lost.

I also found, the problem could be caused by webpack setting, but I it is all i know...

I found, similar problem in different package and they solved this by downgrading d3 package version and load via yarn instead of npm.

It is weird, because their demo working properly, so is there any problem in my webpack settings? Or is there any problem in npm?

**Complete error from console:**

```
*Uncaught TypeError: selection.interrupt is not a function
at Function../node_modules/force-graph/node_modules/d3- 
zoom/src/zoom.js.webpack_exports.default.zoom.transform (zoom.js:90)
at Function../node_modules/force-graph/node_modules/d3- 
zoom/src/zoom.js.webpack_exports.default.zoom.translateBy (zoom.js:119)
at adjustCanvasSize (force-graph.module.js:605)
at Function.init (force-graph.module.js:852)
at u (kapsule.min.js:1)
at Object.r [as comp] (kapsule.min.js:1)
at FromKapsuleComp.componentDidMount (react-kapsule.module.js:85)
at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:14685)
at commitAllLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:15905)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:145)*
```

**webpack.conf.dev.js**

```
 const path = require('path');
 const webpack = require('webpack');
 const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
 const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin');


 module.exports = {
   mode : 'development',
   devtool: 'inline-source-map',
   entry: {
    app: ['./src/index', 'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true']
   },
   output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
   },
   devServer: {
    inline: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
   },
   plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

    //new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './index.html',
        filename: 'index.html',
        inject: 'body',
        title: 'Hot Module Reload'
    }),


    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
    }),

    new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({
        // Your source logo
        logo: './src/img/ikona.png',
        // The prefix for all image files (might be a folder or a name)
        prefix: 'favicon-[hash]/',
        // Emit all stats of the generated icons
        emitStats: false,
        // don't rebuild the favicons until those hashes change
        persistentCache: true,
        // Inject the html into the html-webpack-plugin
        inject: true,
        // favicon background color (see https://github.com/haydenbleasel/favicons#usage)
        background: '#EE3C96',
        // favicon app title (see https://github.com/haydenbleasel/favicons#usage)
        //title: 'Bonobox',
        // which icons should be generated (see https://github.com/haydenbleasel/favicons#usage)
        icons: {
            android: false,
            appleIcon: false,
            appleStartup: false,
            coast: false,
            favicons: true,
            firefox: false,
            opengraph: false,
            twitter: false,
            yandex: false,
            windows: false
        }
    })
],
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ['babel-loader'],
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loaders: ['html-loader'],
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                {loader: "style-loader"},
                {loader: "css-loader"},
                {loader: "sass-loader"}
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [
                {loader: "style-loader"},
                {loader: "css-loader"},
                {loader: "less-loader"}
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                {loader: "style-loader"},
                {loader: "css-loader"}
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json-loader'
        },
        {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
        {test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader?mimetype=application/font-woff"},
        {test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader?mimetype=application/font-woff"},
        {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader?mimetype=application/octet-stream"},
        {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader"},
        {test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|mp4)$/, loader: 'file-loader?limit=8192'}
    ]
}
 };
```

npm version: newest - yesterday updated (error before and also after update)

EDIT: yarn - same problem

Comment: Hi! I am running with the same issue, have you been able to solve it yet?

Comment: I think this is my issue https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/167#issuecomment-459038316 having two different libraries (`d3` and `react-force-graph`) that have d3-selection as a dependency.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late answer. Yes, but the solution is very ugly :) It is exactly as you wrote. The problem was in d3-selection (in the newest version) that was impossible to downgrade because of package.lock file, which automatically locks the oldest dependencies. My solution was, that I cloned the force-graph in which package.json I modified the version of dependency (version without ^). After that I cloned react-force-graph that has modified force-graph as its dependency and this package was finally used in my project :/

Comment: Have a look at this, this is how I solved it https://github.com/vasturiano/react-force-graph/issues/41#issuecomment-481569165